# load svg to html dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg id="svgStageViewPort" version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs id="defs1">
```

how can I load svg elements from external files to "defs1"

1 . using javascript XMLHttpRequest to load external svg file and parse it's elements and append child foreach element to defs1 , is it the best way ?

Comment: Are you trying to load small to medium sized SVG from the server? There's a plugin that does this written by a member of the Raphael group. Raphael renders SVG and VML for IE?

Comment: 15k file size , from the server . I want it to load inside the defs element so it can be "use"

Comment: Maybe populate the defs by writing to the SVG file on the server? I realize this might not fit in with what you are trying to do. The SVG would run faster in the browser with the re-use.

Comment: I'm working now on reading the file using jquery , and looping over the elements and adding childs to the svg defs

Comment: this might help: http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/d3_inkscape/